# Marcar checkbox con un boton jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hola saludos a todos mis amigos. Tengo una pequeña duda.

Quiero seleccionar progresivamente los checkbox que se ven en la imagen al presionar un boton. Por ejemplo, que al presionar el boton se seleccione el primer checkbox, si lo presiono de nuevo se desmarca el primer checkbox  y se selecciona el segundo. Si presiono el boton nuevamente se desmarca el segundo y se marca el tercero y asi sucesivamente hasta el final. Y que cuando llegue al ultimo checkbox si presino el boton se desmarque el ultimo y se marque el primero y se pueda repetir el proceso.

Agradezco mucho su ayuda. Muchas gracias

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Checkbox 1: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
            <td>Checkbox 2: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
            <td>Checkbox 3: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
            <td>Checkbox 4: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
            <td>Checkbox 5: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
            <td>Checkbox 6: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
            <td>Checkbox 7: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
            <td>Checkbox 8: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Marcar" class="button">

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(".button").click(function() { 
                    $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked",true);
            })  
</script>
```

Comment: Buenas, puedes publicar lo que llevas hecho?

Comment: acaso has intentado algo siquiera?

Answer (score 3):

Podés hacerlo con un contador para la posición del checkbox a marcar, y llamar el checkbox deseado usando la función [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) de jquery:

```js
var indice = 0;

$("button").click(function() { 
  // Desmarcar todas las checkboxes
  $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);
  // Marcar únicamente el checkbox que corresponde al índice
  $("input[type=checkbox]").eq(indice++).prop("checked",true);

  // Si el índice llega a la cantidad de checkboxes, reiniciar
  if(indice>=$("input[type=checkbox]").length) indice = 0;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Check!</button>
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Checkbox 1: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
            <td>Checkbox 2: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
            <td>Checkbox 3: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
            <td>Checkbox 4: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
            <td>Checkbox 5: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
            <td>Checkbox 6: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
            <td>Checkbox 7: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
            <td>Checkbox 8: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Hola niche, el problema es que no tengo idea de como hacerlo realmente.

Comment: Te agregué el código del contador

Comment: OMG Bro eres un DIOS!!

Comment: "Los programadores hicimos un pacto con Dios: él no hace sistemas y nosotros no hacemos milagros"

Comment: Recordá [marcar tu respuesta como aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), por si le puede servir a otros usuarios.

Answer (score 3):

Le agregué la clase `mycheckbox` para facilitarlo, te dejo el código documentado.

Saludos

```js
//Cuando el dom este listo
$(()=>{

//Reservamos un indice que inicia en 0
var current_check = 0;

//Evento click
$( document ).on( 'click', '.button', function(){
  
  //Barrer todos los checkbox y quitarles el checked
  $('.mycheckbox').prop('checked', false);
  
  //Crear un selector de checkboxes
  let checkboxes = $('.mycheckbox');
  
  //Poner checkeado el checkbox donde vaya el indice
  $( checkboxes[ current_check ] ).prop('checked',true);
  
  //Dependiendo si el indice es mayor a el numero de checkboxes enlistados se reinicia, si no aumenta
  current_check = current_check >= checkboxes.length -1 ? 0 : current_check + 1;
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Checkbox 1: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="mycheckbox" /></td>
            <td>Checkbox 2: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="mycheckbox"/></td>
            <td>Checkbox 3: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="mycheckbox" /></td>
            <td>Checkbox 4: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="mycheckbox" /></td>
            <td>Checkbox 5: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="mycheckbox" /></td>
            <td>Checkbox 6: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="mycheckbox" /></td>
            <td>Checkbox 7: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="mycheckbox" /></td>
            <td>Checkbox 8: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="mycheckbox" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Marcar" class="button">
```

Answer (score 2):

Para marcar los `checkbox` puedes utilizar el método [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) de JQuery, con el cual puedes obtener el valor de una propiedad o setearla, en el caso de activar los checkbox, la propiedad es `checked`.

Por otro lado, si quieres desmarcar el resto, puedes utilizar el método [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) para setear todos los `checkbox` y que queden desactivados, y posteriormente setear la propiedad `checked' sobre el elemento clickado para que quede activado.

Para ir marcando los inputs puedes agregar un contador e ir desactivando y activando los inputs (desactivas el anterior y activas el siguiente).

Te dejo un ejemplo sencillo para que puedas desarrollarlo e implementarlo en tu proyecto, en el que al marcar todos los checkbox, vuelve al inicio.

```js
//Total de inputs a marcar
var totalInputs = $(".btn").length - 1;
//Contador a 0
var contador = 0;

$(".button").click(function() {
  //Si el contador es mayor o igual que el numero de inputs movemos el contador a 0
  if (contador >= totalInputs) {
    $(".btn").eq(contador).prop("checked", true);
    $(".btn").eq(contador - 1).prop("checked", false);
    contador = 0;
  //Si el contador es 0, borramos el ultimo input y activamos el primero
  } else if (contador === 0){
    $(".btn").eq(contador).prop("checked", true);
    $(".btn").eq(totalInputs).prop("checked", false);
    contador++;
  //Si no, vamos desactivando el anterior y activando el siguiente
  } else {
    $(".btn").eq(contador).prop("checked", true);
    $(".btn").eq(contador - 1).prop("checked", false);
    contador++;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Checkbox 1: <input class="btn" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
  <td>Checkbox 2: <input class="btn" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
  <td>Checkbox 3: <input class="btn" type="checkbox" name="checwkbox[]" /></td>
  <td>Checkbox 4: <input class="btn" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
  <td>Checkbox 5: <input class="btn" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
  <td>Checkbox 6: <input class="btn" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
  <td>Checkbox 7: <input class="btn" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
  <td>Checkbox 8: <input class="btn" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Marcar" class="button">
```

Comment: Hola Asantana muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero no es exactamente lo que busco. Los checkboxs no estan dentro de los botones, estan en una tabla el boton que marca los checkbox esta fuera de la tabla y este debe marcar los checkbox en orden ascendente. Es decir al hacer click en el boton se marca el primer checkbox, al hacer click de nuevo se desmarca el primero y se marca el segundo y asi sucesivamente. Despues de ver ese que hiciste se que facilmente puedes ayudarme con este que te estoy diciendo. eres un pro

Comment: si añades el codigo a tu pregunta puedo ayudarte mejor, porque no se cual es la estuctura de tu codigo ni como lo has intentado

Comment: Hola ASantana ya edite la publicacion con la estructura que tengo